# How to add global "pattern" validator to apply for all fields of type "string" in a json schema pattern

Tags: json, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'm using Ajv JSON schema validator.
I'd like to apply a global Special Characters regex validation for all properties of type "string".
I've saw that there is `allOf` validation that takes an array of condition for example:

```
 allOf: [{maximum: 3}, {type: "integer"}]
```

But when trying to do something like this:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  allof: [{pattern: '[<>%\${}[\]]]'}]
}
```

It's no working.

Comment: Did you solved this? 